# vertical spacing between headings in bootstrap responsive for a page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to develop my web page and i am new to it.
My page has `<h1>`,`<h2`> and `<h3>` .Its title ,heading and subheading for my page.
Now all of them are vertically tightly spaced..so I gave some vertical spacing using , style `margin-bottom:20px`; It works fine.

Is it the right way to do it from bootstrap standard..What is the best way to do this?Is hard coding 20px is ideal?

Comment: What do you mean by "vertically tightly spaced"?

Comment: they dont have much spacing between them

Comment: can you post some code? I don't understand

Comment: Its a general question on how to give vertical spacing between heading tags in bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Default in Bootstrap 3 its have 10px bottom and 20 px on top margin.

```
.h1, .h2, .h3, h1, h2, h3 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```